# .NET Form Post - JPG files er sent fine, PSD files give strange behavior

Tags: c#, .net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, psd

I have a page with an iframe on. I have a form who post to this iframe. The post contains two form fields(one file and one hidden textfield with an ID number). Everything works fine when i choose a JPG, PNG, GIF. The form post to the Iframe and it does as it should.

But when i try to do the same with a 11 mb PSD file it gives me a DNS error (res://ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm#http://localhost:50661/Upload/UploadSingleFile"). When i try to run it through firebug, i see the post being made, but shift to "aborted" within 2 seconds after i post.

I have included this in my web.config under system.webs, to support 50mb content length (file size)

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

You'll need to adjust the maxRequestLength also. Under system.web